# half a $ with the serial numbers question

Tags: united-states

I have a $100 US bill that is torn. Can I use the half with the serial numbers to get my money back from a bank?

I tried to use a vending machine and accidentally put in a 100 dollar bill. It tore it in half. I have a half with the serial numbers. Can I get the money back from the bank or the establishment?

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than 50% of a US bill, it carries the full value and your bank should accept it. (Stores, or banks you do not have an account with, may not.)

If you have less than 50% of the bill, it is worth nothing.

Comment: And if you have *exactly* 50%, I suspect it's also worth nothing.